Bayes rule and terms with expectation
I am reading the following paper in economics;
link
On page 495, authors give an expression with Bayes rule. As an example, say that there is a random variable $\beta$ which can be either $\beta_L$ or $\beta_H$. So, there is an information that you receive, say $T$ such that
$$H_t =\beta X_t+\epsilon_t$$
Let the probability of having a $\beta_H$ is $\pi_t$. Then, with the Bayes rule, we can have
$$\pi_{t+1}=\frac{\pi_{t}exp\left(-p_{\varepsilon}\left(H_{t}-\beta_{H}X_{t}\right)^{2}\right)}{\pi_{t}exp\left(-p_{\varepsilon}\left(H_{t}-\beta_{H}X_{t}\right)^{2}\right)+\left(1-\pi_{t}\right)exp\left(-p_{\varepsilon}\left(H_{t}-\beta_{L}X_{t}\right)^{2}\right)}$$
My question is; is it possible to take the expectation of the probability $\pi$. Normally, is not that $\pi_{t+1}$ is the conditional expectation of $\pi$ on the signal $H$ ?
I ask this question because authors of the paper take the expectation of this probability on page 516. Also, for Bayesian updating (as in Kalman filter), the updated mean (posterior) is the expectation of the random variable, conditional on the signal.
Thanks a lot in advance for any hints/suggestions.

The expectation of $\pi_t$ represents the average belief about the probability that $\beta = \beta_H$ before observing the signal $H_t$. If $\pi_t$ is itself a random variable (which might vary over different scenarios or samples), you can compute its expected value using the following formulas:
$\mathbb{E}[\pi_t] = \sum_{\pi_t} \pi_t \cdot \mathbb{P}(\pi_t)$ for discrete $\pi_t$, or,
$\mathbb{E}[\pi_t] = \int (\pi_t \cdot f(\pi_t)) \, d\pi_t
$ for continuous $\pi_t$, where $f(\pi_t)$ is the probability density function. This approach is consistent with Bayesian principles, where $\pi_t$ might be derived from prior distributions or previous updates in a sequential setting.
In the context of Bayesian updating, $\pi_t$ is often a prior probability that is updated based on new information. The expectation of $\pi_t$ (if considered as a random variable) would represent the average prior belief across different realizations or scenarios before any new data $H_t$ is observed.
Taking the expectation of $\pi_t$ does not necessarily require integration unless $\pi_t$ is a continuous random variable with a known probability density function. In many practical cases, $\pi_t$ can be considered as a deterministic value or a parameter estimated from past data, in which case its expectation is simply the value itself. This is consistent with Bayesian updating principles where the prior is updated to form the posterior distribution based on observed data.
